# Python import list from text file as list

Tags: python, list

```
[2, 'hello', 3, 'good'] - is stored in myfile.txt on one line


 with open(myfile,'r') as f:
        myList = f.readlines()
```

but when I try to retrieve the first index, so "2' by using myList[0], the first square brackets is retrieved.

How can I set the imported line into a list?

Comment: Because it comes as string when you read from file. You can do myList = eval(myList)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.readlines()` method reads lines of text from file, separated with the new line character and returns a list, containing those lines, so that's not the case.

You could have read the contents of the file and eval it like this:

```
with open(myfile,'r') as f:
    my_list = eval(f.read())
```

Note, that the usage of `eval` is considered to be a really bad practice, as it allows to execute any python code written in the file.

Answer (score 2):

use the **[ast](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)** module to convert the string  to a list object

**Ex:**

```
import ast
with open(myfile,'r') as f:
        data= f.read()
        myList = ast.literal_eval(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `json` module for this (since a list is a valid `json` object):

```
import json
with open(myfile) as f:
    myList = json.load(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do:
mylist = mylist[1:-1].split(",") 
[1:-1] gets rid of brackets